# Return model and hash of joined models count grouped in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

Let's say I have two models, Customer and Order.  Order has a status column.  I am trying to avoid an N+1 problem, so I want one query to return with the Customer model with an added "column" which is a hash of each order status with count belonging to that order.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Expected output

```
#<Customer:0x007fb64596ba38> {
    :id => 1,
    :first_name => 'Bob',
    :email => 'test@test.com',
    :order_statuses_count: {shipped: 1, returned: 1, :processing: 0}           
}
```

If anyone has a better idea than my expected output, please let me know.